# Tortoise SVN Add folder option

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use TortoiseSVN 1.7.7, Build 22907 - 64 Bit and my OS is Windows 7 - 64 Bit and having an issue with the `Add folder` option.

In repository browser window, if I right click, I am presented with a menu that has an item `add folder`. I selected this option for adding a folder which contains a large number of source code files[`.c, .cpp, .h`] and some library files with extension `.a` and some object files with `.o`.

After adding this folder when I checked I found that a few `.a` and `.o` files are not added to repository. So I tried adding it again after deleting the old folder from the repository. But again the same files were missing. I tried this a number of times, but to no avail.

Then I tried dragging this folder and dropping it into the repository browser window. This time it worked and no files were missing.

I was thinking `add folder` option is equivalent to dragging an dropping a folder to repository window. But it seems like it is not. If these options are for the same purpose, then could it be a bug? In that case does anybody has similar experience?

Can anybody offer some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is a svn:ignore property set on any parent folder of these .o/.a files. Usually it is better to leave generated content out of the version control, since it causes a lot of conflicts.

Comment: *.o and *. are by default set in TortoiseSVN setting Global Ignore list, so they will never be added.

Comment: @Rudi: Thanks Rudi. So it seems like the result is not the same when I use `Add folder` option and `Folder drag and drop`. In my case these .a/.o files are not generated with the build but it is part of the code base and required for a successful build.